# Tensorflow gradient shape incompatible when using Convolutional Transpose Layer

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I was having an issue when trying to create a convolution-deconvolution network. The original image dimensions are `565 * 584` and I'm trying to produce a segmentation of `565 * 584`.

While I didn't have an issue before with my network with 1024*1024 images, I have been having some issues with these dimensions. I am getting this issue when computing the gradient:

```
segmentation_result.shape: (?, 565, 584, 1), targets.shape: (?, 565, 584, 1)
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):

\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 558, in merge_with


    self.assert_is_compatible_with(other)

\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 106, in assert_is_compatible_with
    other))
ValueError: Dimensions 565 and 566 are not compatible
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()

\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

.py", line 418, in train
    network = Network(net_id = count, weight=pos_weight)

.py", line 199, in __init__
    self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(self.cost)

\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py", line 315, in minimize
    grad_loss=grad_loss)

\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py", line 386, in compute_gradients

    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)

\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py", line 560, in gradients
    in_grad.set_shape(t_in.get_shape())

\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 443, in set_shape
    self._shape = self._shape.merge_with(shape)

\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 561, in merge_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are not compatible" % (self, other))

ValueError: Shapes (?, 565, 584, 64) and (?, 566, 584, 64) are not compatible
```

The entire network has 10 convolutional layers and 10 deconvolutional layers. Each deconvolutional layer is a reversed version of the forward layer. Here is an example of the code to produce the convolutional layer:

```
def create_layer_reversed(self, input, prev_layer=None):
    net_id = self.net_id
    print(net_id)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv', reuse=False):
        W = tf.get_variable('W{}_{}_'.format(self.name[-3:], net_id),
                            shape=(self.kernel_size, self.kernel_size, self.input_shape[3], self.output_channels))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([W.get_shape().as_list()[2]]))

    output = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(
        input, W,
        tf.stack([tf.shape(input)[0], self.input_shape[1], self.input_shape[2], self.input_shape[3]]),
        strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

    Conv2d.layer_index += 1
    output.set_shape([None, self.input_shape[1], self.input_shape[2], self.input_shape[3]])

    output = lrelu(tf.add(tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(output), b))

    return output
```

Comment: I found that one of the issues was after several layers of max-pooling the output shape was becoming too small; this has seemingly resolved this particular bug.